# new password and confirm password should not be same as current password. how to restrict it in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to validate current password , new password and confirm password in ruby on rails. When I click change password it will ask to enter current,new and confirm password. but when I accidentally enter the same password in "current password" and "new password" field it should not allow it. it should throw some error message like "current password and new password can't be same". but really I don’t know how to do this in ruby on rails. please anyone help me if you know the answer. thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have passwords (I hope encrypted) stored in a DB or backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a custom line to my update method within my users_controller.rb file. I imagine it currently looks something like this?

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if @user.update(usere_params)
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

I would add a couple lines to this file and make sure that the new and current password are not the same, and if so, return a validation error.

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

  if params[:user][:new_password] == prams[:user][:current_password]
    @user.errors.add(:new_password, 'Can not use current password')
  end

  if !@user.errors.any? and @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

This will cause `if !@user.errors.any? and @user.update(user_params)` to be false (because there is already an error) and simply run the `render 'edit'` line (which normally displays your validation errors if you have it set up that way).

Comment: Oh my god!!! It works for me...Great...thank you thank you than you..thanks a lot Ken Stipek.. You did a great job...You saved me from a great trouble. Thanks a lot